# If a boot fails, will the computer try doing something differently the next time?

Tags: 16.04

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

If the machine fails to boot, the next time it will boot successfully, but all the loading screens will be at 640x480 resolution.

If the machine boots successfully, the next time it tries to boot it will have a 1920x1200 Ubuntu loading screen (where it asks me to enter my password to unlock the hard disk), but will freeze and not let me enter the password.

Which log file will tell me why it freezes at that point?

How does Ubuntu know that it failed during the previous boot attempt?